# Left arrow and home key stop working in sublime python repl after making repl a separate window

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

Mac OSX 10.11, Sublime 3, REPL 1.0.30

When I open a python REPL (tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python), it always opens as a new/current tab in the current sublime window.

While the REPL is tabbed, both the left arrow and home key function as they should (move cursor left per keypress, start of line). When I drag the repl tab to make it its own window, the left arrow and home keys stop working. All other arrow keys and end key function as expected.

If I press left arrow at the end of a line of text, like

```
def foo(bar):
```

instead of moving the cursor to the left of the colon, nothing happens.

However, I can see in the other sublime text window that the cursor is ghosting across that text. For instance, if the current position on the non-repl sublime text window is "Line 87, Column 13" pressing the left arrow key in the REPL window will do nothing in the REPL window, but change the cursor position of the non-REPL window accordingly (change cursor pos to "Line 87, Column 12"). Typing, of course, remains within repl, despite the left/home keys being mapped to the cursor pos in the non-repl window. Cursor position does not change with moving right with right arrow or end.

Does anyone know a way to fix this issue? Thanks for your consideration, at any rate.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, it's exactly the same for me. Maybe we should file an issue on the sublime repl repo (https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues)

Answer (score 1):

I just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/pull/519) to the SublimeREPL repo that I believe should fix this -- so far I've been able to test it with ST3 under Windows 10. (ST3 build 3126, SublimeREPL 2.1.2.)

This said, the SublimeREPL pull request queue appears to be a bit backed up at the moment... I can plan to circle back once the fix has been merged.

Comment: Awesome, I hope they pull. I found a work-around by just dragging the non-repl tabs into their own windows instead of the repl tab.